# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhogweed

Tags: c, compilation, makefile, ssl

I;m trying to compile GnuTLS. When I thy to configure the package I get this error:

```
configure:8820: gcc -std=gnu99 -o conftest -g -O2   conftest.c  -lnettle -lhogweed -lgmp >&5
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhogweed
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I searched google for `hogweed` but there is no such a package? How I can fix this problem?

Comment: Just don't distribute any binaries made from linking GMP with a GPLv2-only program or you will be violating the GPLv2-only license agreements.  Nettle uses GMP by default and that conveys "must be GPLv3 compatible" up the stack.  Go look at how CUPS is licensed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When linking with libraries you remove the `lib` from their name and append it to `-l`
ie for example `libcrypto` library will be linked by passing option `-lcrypto`
in your case its is `-lhogweed` that is missing. That means `libhogweed` library is missing.

A simple Google search of 'libhogweed' shows that its a part of 'GNU Nettle cryptographic library'. So you can install this and fix your problem.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to install the Nettle cryptographic library. As you didn't post your OS, I can't give more details.

More information on Nettle and Hogweed: http://www.lysator.liu.se/~nisse/nettle/nettle.html#Linking

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnutls/2012-01/msg00019.html) message, you need to build Nettle after you install GMP. Try to rebuild Nettle and see if it gets built.